# How to ask "the places you have been planning to go " informally

Tags: phrase-request

One of my friends ask me to have a ride with him, and I want to ask what are the places you have been planning to go (assume going to go multiple places)
How could I ask informally, what's the most suitable phrase?

Answer (score 6):

This can be covered a number of very simple ways.

There's the popular "Where are we going?" This indicates a tentative agreement to go. Similarly, you might use the simple and direct "Where are you going?" A native speaker, depending on local dialect, might even say "Where *all* are you/we going?" if multiple destinations are expected.

You can also ask "Where do you plan on going?"

Further, there are a number of even more informal, idiomatic ways of asking the question. You might ask "What's the plan?" or "Where to?" or even something vague like "What's up?" -- anything that connotes a general query about the reason for a trip or the destination. You could even simply ask, "Why?" though that connotes suspicion or a suspicious nature.

Answer (score 1):

Two phrases you might be looking for are

> Where are you thinking of going?
>   Where are you considering going?

They are both emphasize the "planning" part of travelling.